# How to verify two hashed password that were hashed with php's password_hash() function

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

Is there a way i can *unhash* a password, or atleast check if two hashes (hashed with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash)) give the same value if unhashed ?

Because i have a token page which contains a hashed password and a users table which also contains a hashed password and i want to check if the password are the same but the problem is that `password_hash()` does not always give the same value even if the password is the same and `password_verify()` need one value to be normal text, so how can I verify that the token password and user password are the same ?

Comment: [Password hashes can't be "unhashed"](https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/)

Comment: @jps then how do i know if token pass and user pass are the same

Comment: You calculate a hash from the plain text password, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, period. That's the entire point of `password_hash` and its *random salt*: if you have two hashes, you don't know if they're for the same password. That prevents brute-forcing an entire database of hashes by an attacker, since the attacker can't amortise brute-force time invested into one hash by matching other hashes.

Comment: Then how do i know if they are the same

Comment: You don't. You need the plaintext password and test both against it.

Comment: So i should keep unhashed password in token database

Comment: God no, that undermines the entire point of hashing passwords in the first place! You can do the comparison when the user logs in, for example. At that point, you do have the plaintext password and can compare both hashes to it. I don't know why you want to, but that's one possibility. Beyond that you should think about why you need these two separate hashes at all.

Comment: @googol If you could break your password system, you shouldn't be using it in the first place. The equivalent of a locksmith would be a password reset.

Comment: +1. If an app or business workflow has "check to see if two users have the same password" as a requirement, that workflow is fundamentally flawed and needs to be rearchitected. In other words: if a system can produce information about the contents of someone's password. that system is broken and dangerous.